# I need to add $10 USDC to 60 wallets using Transaction Builder by tonight

Tags: gnosis-safe

I understand that I need to paste the USDC Ethereum contract address and not my own safe address that contains the USDC. Once I pasted the address, this popped up. What is the difference between a proxy ABI and implementation ABI? [image: First question: what should I choose if I want to get tokens sent?]

Then, I assume I select transfer, because I want to transfer USDC. But then there's also the transferFrom option, so is there a right answer here?

[image: transfer or transferfrom?]

Answer (score 0):

When you are interacting with a Proxy contract, you are not really interested in the proxy ABI itself. Etherscan gives you the option to read and write in your proxy contract as if it was the implementation one.

Otherwise you would need to ABI encode the function call and pass it to fallback() which can be messy. So stick with Read as Proxy and Use Implementation ABI.

You can use either `transfer(address to, uint amount)` or `transferFrom(address from, address to, uint amount)` the only difference is that transferFrom has an additional parameter, `from` because it is normally used together with `approve(address spender uint amount)` to give permissions to a third smart contract or wallet to move assets on your behalf (like a NFT marketplace contract)